# jquery bind and unbind

Tags: jquery

i have a .hover that when it is clicked i need to unbind and then when another element is click in need to bind again any suggestion on how to get it to work with the following code.

```
$('ul li.port a, ul li.serv a,ul li.cont a, ul li.test a').hover(
  function() {  
    $('span', this)
      .stop()
      .animate({margin: '15px', left:'+=50',opacity: 1}, 200);
      $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 200);           
  }, 
  function() {
    $('span', this)
      .stop()
      .animate({margin: '0px',opacity: 0}, 200);
      $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 0},200); 
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can unbind like this:

```
$('ul li.port a, ul li.serv a,ul li.cont a, ul li.test a').hover(
  function() {  
    $('span', this)
      .stop()
      .animate({margin: '15px', left:'+=50',opacity: 1}, 200);
      $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 200);           
  }, 
  function() {
    $('span', this)
      .stop()
      .animate({margin: '0px',opacity: 0}, 200);
      $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 0},200); 
  }
).click(function() {
    $(this).unbind("hover")
});
```

Notice the added click event.

To re-add the hover, just call the code again.  I usually put things like this that will get called multiple times in a separate function, `BindHoverEvent` in the below example.

```
$('#otherElement').click(function() { BindHoverEvent(); });
```

Comment: i have it working like this
$('ul li a').click(function() {
 $(this).unbind('mouseenter').unbind('mouseleave');      
});

but when i click on another element i cant get it to bind again

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean flag variable and change it to true and false and in your hover functions check the flag before executing the rest of the function.

OR

Another way is to unbind mouse enter and mouse leave. Apparently that removed the hover event:

```
$('ul li.port a, ul li.serv a,ul li.cont a, ul li.test a').unbind('mouseenter','mouseleave');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//now whenever hover elm is clicked its event will be removed
$('.hover').one('click',null,_handlerFn);

//bind handler fn hover class when other elm ic clicked
$('.anotherElm').bind('click',null,function(){$('.hover').one('click',null,_handlerFn);});
```

Answer (score 0):

i use on click but it should be about the same. i bind on click and then unbind when mouseleve

```
$("#langue_box").live("click",function(){
      $(this).addClass("show");
      req_content("langue_box","my_user","langue","show");
      $("#langue_box").bind("mouseleave",function(){
      $(this).removeClass("show");
      req_content("langue_box","my_user","langue","hide");
     $("#langue_box").unbind("mouseleave");
    });
    });
```